# I'm having problems understanding how to get a variable out of this ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a Recipe Box for school and I need help understanding how to access a single variable inside an ArrayList.  I only need to access the totalCalories variable in the recipe file, not the ingredient so that I can add the total number of calories in the recipe itself.  Here is the code.

```
package recipebox;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Recipe {

private String recipeName;
private int servings;
private ArrayList recipeIngredients;
private double totalRecipeCalories;


public String getRecipeName() {
    return recipeName;
}

public void setRecipeName(String recipeName) {
    this.recipeName = recipeName;
}

public double getTotalRecipeCalories() {
    return totalRecipeCalories;
}

public void setTotalRecipeCalories(double totalRecipeCalories) {
    this.totalRecipeCalories = totalRecipeCalories;
}

public ArrayList getRecipeIngredients() {
    return recipeIngredients;
}

public void setRecipeIngredients(ArrayList recipeIngredients) {
    this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
}

public int getServings() {
    return servings;
}

public void setServings(int servings) {
    this.servings = servings;
}

public Recipe() {
    this.recipeName = "";
    this.servings = 0;
    this.recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
    this.totalRecipeCalories = 0;

}
public Recipe(String recipeName, int servings, ArrayList <String> recipeIngredients, double totalRecipeCalories) {
    this.recipeName = recipeName;
    this.servings = servings;
    this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
    this.totalRecipeCalories = totalRecipeCalories;
}

public void printRecipe() {
    int singleServingCalories = (int)(totalRecipeCalories/getServings());
    System.out.println("Recipe: " + getRecipeName());
    System.out.println("Serves: " + getServings());
    System.out.println("Ingredients:");
    System.out.println(recipeIngredients);
    System.out.println("Each serving has " + singleServingCalories + " Calories.");
}

public void addIngredient() {
    recipeIngredients.add(Ingredient.createNewIngredient());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createNewRecipe();
}

public static Recipe createNewRecipe() {
    double totalRecipeCalories = 0;
    ArrayList <String> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList();
    boolean addMoreIngredients = true;

    Recipe myRecipe = new Recipe();

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the recipe name: ");
    while (!scnr.hasNextLine()){ 
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("Please enter the recipe name: ");
        scnr.nextLine();
    }
    String recipeName = scnr.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of servings: ");
    while (!scnr.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of servings: ");
        scnr.nextLine();
    }
    int servings = scnr.nextInt();


    do {
        myRecipe.addIngredient();
totalRecipeCalories += recipeIngredients.get(totalCalories);
```

I didn't include the rest of it since it won't matter.  That last line is wrong and is the one that needs fixing.  Now here is the ingredient code.

```
package recipebox;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ingredient {

private String nameOfIngredient;
private float numberUnits;
private String unitMeasurement;
private int numberCaloriesPerUnit;
private double totalCalories;

/**
 * @return the nameOfIngredient
 */
public String getNameOfIngredient() {
    return nameOfIngredient;
}

/**
 * @param nameOfIngredient the nameOfIngredient to set
 */
public void setNameOfIngredient(String nameOfIngredient) {
    this.nameOfIngredient = nameOfIngredient;
}

/**
 * @return the numberUnits
 */
public float getNumberUnits() {
    return numberUnits;
}

/**
 * @param numberUnits the numberUnits to set
 */
public void setNumberUnits(float numberUnits) {
    this.numberUnits = numberUnits;
}

/**
 * @return the numberCaloriesPerUnit
 */
public int getNumberCaloriesPerUnit() {
    return numberCaloriesPerUnit;
}

/**
 * @param numberCaloriesPerUnit the numberCaloriesPerUnit to set
 */
public void setNumberCaloriesPerUnit(int numberCaloriesPerUnit) {
    this.numberCaloriesPerUnit = numberCaloriesPerUnit;
}

/**
 * @return the totalCalories
 */
public double getTotalCalories() {
    return totalCalories;
}

/**
 * @param totalCalories the totalCalories to set
 */
public void setTotalCalories(double totalCalories) {
    this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
}

/**
 * @return the unitMeasurement
 */
public String getUnitMeasurement() {
    return unitMeasurement;
}

/**
 * @param unitMeasurement the unitMeasurement to set
 */
public void setUnitMeasurement(String unitMeasurement) {
    this.unitMeasurement = unitMeasurement;
}

public Ingredient() {
    this.nameOfIngredient = "";
    this.numberUnits = 0.00f;
    this.unitMeasurement = "";
    this.numberCaloriesPerUnit = 0;
    this.totalCalories = 0.0;
}

public Ingredient(String nameOfIngredient, float numberUnits, String unitMeasurement, int numberCaloriesPerUnit, double totalCalories) {
    this.nameOfIngredient = nameOfIngredient;
    this.numberUnits = numberUnits;
    this.unitMeasurement = unitMeasurement;
    this.numberCaloriesPerUnit = numberCaloriesPerUnit;
    this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
}

public static Ingredient createNewIngredient() {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ingredient: ");
    while (!scnr.hasNextLine()){ 
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the ingredient: ");
        scnr.nextLine();
    }
    String nameOfIngredient = scnr.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What unit of measurement will you be using? ");
    while (!scnr.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("What unit of measurement will you be using? ");
        scnr.nextLine();
    }
    String unitMeasurement = scnr.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of " + unitMeasurement + " of " + nameOfIngredient + " we will need: ");
    while (!scnr.hasNextFloat()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of " + unitMeasurement + " of " + nameOfIngredient + " we will need: ");
        scnr.nextLine();
    }
    float numberUnits = scnr.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per " + unitMeasurement + ": ");
    while (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of calories per " + unitMeasurement + ": ");
        scnr.nextLine();
    }
    int numberCaloriesPerUnit = scnr.nextInt();

    double totalCalories = numberUnits * numberCaloriesPerUnit;
    System.out.println(nameOfIngredient + " uses " + numberUnits + " " + unitMeasurement + " and has " + totalCalories + " calories.");

recipebox.Ingredient tempIngredient = new recipebox.Ingredient(nameOfIngredient, numberUnits, unitMeasurement, numberCaloriesPerUnit, totalCalories);
return tempIngredient;
}

}
```

Now when I debug the recipe file, right after it returns from getting the ingredients, I can see in the variables list the variable I need, but I can't figure out how to get to it.

[This is what the debug variable menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPX8Y.jpg)

If someone can help me access that one variable and maybe explain in beginner terms how you did it, I'd be very grateful.  Thanks.

Comment: maybe try reading the documentation of ArrayList to see if it has a method to [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) element 0 ?

Comment: You should complete your `do-while` loop

Comment: In your code `System.out.println(recipeIngredients);`. Are you sure that it prints in the Right way? Never tried that way

Comment: Good eye, that's actually from the previous code when the ingredients were collected from the recipe file itself.  That's really why recipeIngredients needs to collect the ingredients into an array, so it will print out everything when the recipeBox program calls for it.

Answer (score 2):

The variable recipeIngredients is a List and not an object. The list contains object of type Ingredient. So to the value of the total calories from an ingredient in the list you need to access a particular ingredient in that list first and then take its property.

So it would be `recipeIngredients.get(0).getTotalCalories()` - to get the total calories for the first ingredient in the list

If you want it for the whole recepy you would need a loop that goes through that list and calculates. Something like:

```
int calories;
for(Object ingredient: recipeIngredients)
 calories+= ((Ingredient)ingredient).getTotalCalories();
```

Also in the code:

```
 System.out.println(recipeIngredients);
```

You will not print anything useful for the same reason. You need to go through each ingredient and print it in a pretty way.

You might also consider making that list of type Ingredient using generics so you don't need to cast and you are using it just for ingredients anyway

Comment: wouldn't be a typecast neccessary here since `recipeIngredients` is declared as `ArrayList` and not as `ArrayList<Ingredients>` and therefore `List.get()` returning an object of the type `Object`?

Comment: the System.out.println(recipeIngredients); is being called from the recipeBox program.  I originally had all of the ingredients in the recipe file but had to move it out.